# Angularjs/ionic/cordova read sms list form phone

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, sms

I'm developing a multi platforms app using Angularjs, Ionic and Cordova.
I need a cordova plugin for read a SMS inbox list from phone and show this list on Ionic view via Angularjs.

I have found this plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms?files=1

In console.log(data) it return me this array -> "Array[0], length 0"

This is the code (it is inside $ionicPlatform.ready() and I have enabled READ_SMS permission):

```
var filter = {
                box: 'inbox', // 'inbox' (default), 'sent', 'draft', 'outbox', 'failed', 'queued', and '' for all

                // following 4 filters should NOT be used together, they are OR relationship
                //read: 1, // 0 for unread SMS, 1 for SMS already read
                //_id: 1, // specify the msg id
                //address: '334444555', // sender's phone number
                body: 'This is a test SMS', // content to match

                // following 2 filters can be used to list page up/down
                indexFrom: 0, // start from index 0
                maxCount: 10, // count of SMS to return each time
            };
                if (SMS)
                    SMS.listSMS(filter, function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

Best regards and thanks to all.

Comment: Well, where is the approch you are following, you must be making a mistake, device ready maybe?

Comment: I have add a code - Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to declare 'SMS', add `declare var SMS: any;` before `@Component({ ... })`.

Then, to list SMSs, you must extract all values from the JSON (your data is in a JSON). To do this, you just need to add `JSON.stringify(data);` and delete `function` before `data` like that :

```
if(SMS) SMS.listSMS(filter, (data)=>{
 JSON.stringify(data);
 if(Array.isArray(data)) {
    for(var data in data) {
        this.msg = ListSms[data].address;
    }
}
},Error=>{}),
```

So, the variable this.msg have now all of the smss.